# Python removes duplicate from m3u playlist

Tags: python-2.7

I have m3u playlist like below (infilename):

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:0, name 1
link 1
#EXTINF:0, name 2
link 2
#EXTINF:0, name 3
link 1
#EXTINF:0, name 4
link 4
#EXTINF:0, name 5
link 1
#EXTINF:0, name 6
link 6
.......
.......
```

Here is the output that I like to have (outfilename):

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:0, name 1
link 1
#EXTINF:0, name 2
link 2
#EXTINF:0, name 4
link 4
#EXTINF:0, name 6
link 6
.......
.......
```

Each item contains two lines: 1 line for its name and 1 line for its link. Items also considered to be duplicate if they have same links. I have used set() to remove these duplicates, but it removed only their links and left their names intact. How can I remove entire duplicate items?

Here is the code that i've used (got from internet)

```
infilename = path to infilename
outfilename = path to outfilename

lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
for line in open(infilename, "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your solution is the following: You will always write the name line, no matter if the link is a duplicate or not, since the name line is first in the file. One way to solve this (and probably not the most elegant, but it works is):

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")

# Flag to keep track if the next line is supposed to be a link
nextLineLink=False 

for line in open(infilename, "r"):

    # Check if the current line is a name line 
    if line.startswith("#EXTINF"):
        info=line
        nextLineLink=True
        continue

    # If we encounter an empty line, set back flag
    # Otherwise we would write the last info too 
    if line.strip()=="":
        nextLineLink=False
        continue

    # Check if this line is supposed to be a link
    if nextLineLink:

        # Check if we already seen the line
        if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate

            # Write both lines and add
            outfile.write(info)
            outfile.write(line)
            lines_seen.add(line)

            # Set back flag
            nextLineLink=False


outfile.close()
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Yeah, it works great. Just added outfile.write('#EXTM3U\n\n') to the third line, then bam, got exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you mark the question as answered then, so no one else is trying to answer it?